# MongoDB and C# - Large Document retrievals

Tags: c#, mongodb, indexing

We are saving e-mail documents in several MongoDB collection. In general, a document would look like this:

```
_id : 5f4d92e25ea74a21487bd25b
MailGuid: "20200901021619-03659434082D04F09F85C6ED6C6CA80FD9F7521846823A614E34943..."
Date: 2020-09-01T00:16:19.000+00:00
From:
  DisplayName: "Joe Soap"
  Host: "companya.com"
  User: "JoeS"
  Address: "joes@companya.com"
Sender:
  DisplayName: ""
  Host: ""
  User: ""
  Address: ""
To: 
  0: 
    DisplayName: "Harry Person "
    Host: "companyb.com"
    User: "Harry.Person"
    Address: "harryp@companyb.com"
  1: 
    DisplayName: "Fred Someone"
    Host: "companyb.com"
    User: "Fred.Someone"
    Address: freds@companyb.com"
Cc:
Bcc:
Subject: "I found your toothpick"
BodyContentType: 2
Priority: 1
Sensitivity: 1
Size: 21035
Attachments: 
  0:
    FileName: "pick.jpg"
StorageLocation : ""
MD5HashClean: ""
MD5HashEncrypted: ""
SHA512Clean: ""
SHA512Encrypted: ""
Flagged: false
Headers:
  0:
    Key: "Received"
    Value: "from DB7PR09MB2300.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com (2603:10a6:10:40::20) by ..."
  1:
    Key: "From"
    Value: "Joe Soap" <joes@companya.com>"
  etc...

MailId: "b97a80d1d94c4c528934d6fe71f27228@DB7PR09MB2300.eurprd09.prod.outlook.c..."
MailIds:
  0: "b97a80d1d94c4c528934d6fe71f27228@DB7PR09MB2300.eurprd09.prod.outlook.c..."
  1: "AdZZLBUvIxzUnu4LT+iV9gJ9NVWKEQAhxPHQADuOndAAARp2sAAAU5dQADCZE+AAARmykA..."
  2: "AM6PR05MB4439C8694422DB61B8E1353AF82E0@AM6PR05MB4439.eurprd05.prod.out..."
  3:  "f6167405-6e9d-431d-b104-08d84e0c4064"
```

The problem comes in that running any sort of query on this data becomes incredibly slow except if you are running it on the date ranges. A simple count of documents based on a filter can take over 2 minutes and then sometimes it can be very fast.
Because multiple different fields can be queried and we can't predict which fields will need to be queried, I have created indexes up the whazoo for everything and it's dog that I can think of and it doesn't make a difference.

An example of some of the queries would be (generated using LINQ)

```
{ "$or" : [{ "_id" : { "$type" : -1 } }, { "From.Address" : /joe/s }, { "From.DisplayName" : /joe/is }], "Date" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2020-09-30T22:00:00Z"), "$lt" : ISODate("2020-10-14T21:59:59Z") } }

{ "$or" : [{ "_id" : { "$type" : -1 } }, { "To" : { "$elemMatch" : { "$or" : [{ "Address" : /freds@companyb\.com/s }, { "DisplayName" : /freds@companyb\.com/is }] } } }, { "To" : { "$elemMatch" : { "$or" : [{ "Address" : /harryp@companyb\.com/s }, { "DisplayName" : /harryp@companyb\.com/is }] } } }], "Date" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2020-09-30T22:00:00Z"), "$lt" : ISODate("2020-10-14T21:59:59Z") } }

{ "$and" : [{ "$or" : [{ "_id" : { "$type" : -1 } }, { "From.Address" : /joe/s }, { "From.DisplayName" : /joe/is }] }, { "$or" : [{ "_id" : { "$type" : -1 } }, { "Subject" : /toothpick/is }] }, { "$or" : [{ "_id" : { "$type" : -1 } }, { "Attachments.FileName" : /\.jpg/is }] }, { "Date" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2020-09-30T22:00:00Z"), "$lt" : ISODate("2020-10-14T21:59:59Z") } }] }
```

If anyone can see something I'm doing wrong or advice on how to index this data or advice on how you would run queries, I'm all ears..

Comment: Many of your searches are for "contains" and can't use indexes. That is bound to be slow. If you can use "starts with" instead you should get index support and much better response times. In other words use /^joe/ instead of /joe/.

Comment: What database is being used in backend?